# Why virtual function from base class cannot be overridden as static in derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static

I have following code:

```
//base
class base  
{  
public :  
  virtual void func(){  
    cout<<"Base::func"<< endl;  
}  
};  

class derived : public base  
{  
public :  
     static void func() // overridden function
{  
    cout<<"derived::func"<< endl;  
}  
};
```

Here, I have overridden the func() in derived class as static. Why compiler won't allow this?

Comment: for once  because the language doesn't allow it. Then because it wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, like, at all. `func` in base is called in the context of a particular instance of `base`. `func` from `derived` is to be called always as `derived::func`, without any object - how can it "override" the former?

Comment: @Mark: That dupe is nearly even relevant for this question. Trouble is, nearly a hit is still a miss.

Comment: The answer is, because a static method and a non-static methot simply aren't all that similar. What I wonder though is why it does not allow hiding it.

Comment: @Deduplicator There's a possibility I misunderstood the question. The OP used "overridden" rather than "hiding" or "replacing" so I assumed they wanted the virtualness to fall through to the derived class, which is answered by my linked duplicate.

Comment: @Mark: The base-class-function is not `static`, which means the explanation in the dupe does not really fit.